# Android AppCompat Revision 21 issue

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I downloaded the last v7 Support Library AppCompat (revision 21) using SDK Manager in eclipse.

I created an ActionBar and saw the result and I did not like it, it's ugly and not comfort (Android 5.0 Style).
Now I want to use revision 18 or 19.
I searched a lot in Google for previous revisions for download and I did not find nothing.

What can I do to get the previous result (No Lollipop [Android 5.0]) ?

- Is somebody can upload a Library-Project of previous revision ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you will need to read about [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) features based on the revision. Then, read [how to install SDK offline](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html). After you are understand about that, you can download the Support Library here:

[revision 19](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.zip)

[revision 18](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r18.zip)

If you aren't understand about installing SDK offline above, you must copy your downloaded `.zip` file into  "~..\android-sdk\extras\android\[unzip downloaded]" directory. Then unzip your downloaded `.zip` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your sdk folder you can find all older releases.

Check the folder:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7
```

Here you should find these folders:

```
18.0.0
19.0.0
19.0.1
...
21.0.0
21.0.2
```

In your eclipse, you have to build the library in your workspace, using the info described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), using your preferred release.

If you are using Android Studio, it is very easy. Just choose 1 release in your dependency block.

```
dependencies {

    // Support Libraries - USE ONLY 1 RELEASE!
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.x.X'

    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```